# Use the Boolean.valueOf() method vs (or Java 1.5 autoboxing) to create Boolean objects

Tags: java, performance

Which is the better practice between  `Boolean.valueOf()` and `Java 1.5 autoboxing` to create `Boolean` from `booleans` and why ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Autoboxing of `boolean` is transparently translated to `Boolean.valueOf()` by the compiler:

```
boolean b = true;
Boolean bb = b;
```

is translated to:

```
iconst_1
istore_1            //b = 1 (true)
iload_1             //b
invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
astore_2            //bb = Boolean.valueOf(b)
```

Use whichever you find more useful and readable. Since using `Boolean.valueOf()` is not giving you anything except extra typing, you should aim for autoboxing.

---

Situation complicates when you think about opposite conversion - from `Boolean` to `boolean`. This time `Boolean.booleanValue()` is called transparently for you by the compiler, which can theoretically cause `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Maintainability is key. Even if they didn't end up compiling to identical bytecode, they would be equivalent enough that readability would be the driving factor.

Comment: I personally prefer an explicit valueOf(), that makes it very clear that a conversion to wrapper type occurs. Of course, this is only personal preference.

Comment: @Thomasz how it can possibly cause a NPE ? I do not get that part .

Comment: @Geek: `Boolean bb = null; boolean b = bb` is translated to `bb.booleanValue()` and will throw NPE during unboxing.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I see what you are saying . Thanks for the explanation.